# Is there a Data Grid for the Watch window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

There used to be a Visual Studio extension that would allow viewing data in a grid while debugging in Visual Studio. I am looking around online, and cannot find one.

Does anybody know of an Extension for Visual Studio 2013 that allows viewing data sets or collections in a grid while debugging?

Comment: I'm not sure why this got downvoted. I had a question, somebody offered an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are looking for [OzCode](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/36925113-cdce-4953-a5d6-fb3d2912dad7/description#Reveal):

[image]