# Visual Studio QuickWatch - How to find quickly an item in collection in QuickWatch window

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, watch

I have observable collection called m_Tree. It contains objects of Planet type which has property Name.  The collection could have hundreds of items in it.  How do I quickly find a Planet.Name="Jupiter" in QuickWatch window in VS?

Currently, I have to manually expand each car in the collection and look for its Name but that can be troubling.  Lambda expressions or LINQ do not work in QuickWatch as far as I can see.

Here is what I tried with LINQ

```
from item in m_Tree where item.Name == "Jupiter" select item
```

but QuickWatch shows error

> from item in m_Tree where item.Name == "Jupiter" select item
>   Expression cannot contain query expressions

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264959/is-there-a-data-grid-for-the-watch-window-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 4):

I created a [commercial extension for Visual Studio](http://o.oz-code.com/features) that solves exactly this problem. OzCode replaces the normal QuickWatch and DataTip (hover over variable) windows. If you're just looking for the property value as text, you can use the Search feature:

[image: Search]

But if you want to "Jupiter" only when its the value in the "Name" property, not in any other property, you can use OzCode's Filter:
[image: Filter]

And type in `[obj].Name == "Jupiter"` as your predicate.

Comment: Nice! I think this will indeed satisfy the OP's requirement. +1 for the nice animation.

Comment: Thanks, it is useful.  I dont think that OzCode is free though.

Comment: @cd491415， if Omer‘s suggestion is helpful for you, would you please mark it as the answer? So it could help other community members who meet the same issues.

Comment: @Omer Thanks.  While your answer is great, I am looking for a free way to do this.  I would expect VS 2013 has a way to allow this quite needed and obvious feature.

Answer (score 1):

Though my answer is not about doing it in QuickWatch, it may help you get the job done.

While in debug mode, you can use the [Immediate Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx) to do that. If not already open, open Immediate Window, and execute your query.

```cs
var jupiters = (from item in m_Tree where item.Name == "Jupiter" select item).ToList();
jupiters  // prints the objects in the Immediate Window
```

I use Immediate Window a lot, and find it very helpful. Hope that helps you too.

Comment: Note that OP tagged this as a VS2013 question, and what you're suggesting will only work in VS2015 and up.

Comment: Oops, I didn't know that it's not available in VS2013. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks but LINQ or lambdas wont work in Immediate window nor QuickWatch, I tried that before posting this question.